# Is there a prefix that indicates that an event recurs four times a year?

Tags: prefixes, recurring-events

"Semi-annually" describes an event that recurs every 6 months. Is there a similar term for an event that recurs every 3 months? (I'm guessing that "semi-semi-annually" isn't the correct answer.)

More importantly, is there a resource or table somewhere that I can use in the future to construct prefixes for other intervals shorter than a year?

Comment: Note that if you wished to employ multiple prefixes the relevant analogy would be in music: *quaver*, *semiquaver*, *demisemiquaver*, *hemidemisemiquaver*. That is, you would not repeat *semi-* but add *demi-*.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is not exactly a prefix but the word does indeed refer to an event that occurs four times a year. And the word is "Quarterly".

Comment: This got you so many upboats?? why was i not here earlier?? *sobs*

Comment: Blame George Edison. :P

Answer (score 5):

> More importantly, is there a resource or table somewhere that I can use in the future to construct prefixes for other intervals shorter than a year?

Not really, because commonly used ones are often exceptions to rules. However, you now have a good set:

- Annually (and the multiplicators)
- Bianually
- Quarterly
- Monthly (there should be a word for every two months)
- Fortnightly
- Weekly

...

Now you only have problems if you need to define every 6 weeks or suchlike.

Comment: Sesquimonthly would be a close approximation for 6 weeks.

Comment: @zzzzBov - I think using that in normal conversation might prove interesting. There are words for a range of different periods, but whether they actually work in communication is another matter.

Comment: When the purpose is for unambiguous communication, "6 weeks" would obviously be the preferred descriptor. Not all language is meant to be unambiguous simple communication; poetry and music often choose words with a richer meaning.

Comment: There's potentially [confusion around biannual](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/biannual); also consider *semiannual*.

Comment: @zzzzBov I am not saying that you are wrong, just that, as you point out, the aim is clear communication.

Comment: *there should be a word for every two months* - You can use the word *bimonthly* but it can also mean *twice a year* which can be confusing.

Comment: @AlexandreJasmin - I agree. That was why I didn't use it. I wanted bilunally or similar, but that was too obscure!

Comment: Biweekly for every two weeks (or fortnightly if you aren't in the USA).  Bimonthly for every two months.  Trimonthly would be a possibility, but 'quarterly' is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

If

> quarterly

doesn't suffice,

> tri-monthly

is probably closest in spirit to "semi-annually" (although I would prefer "biannual" to this anyway)

You should be able to construct such a table reasonably easily.

```
weekly           every week
bi-weekly        every two weeks
tri-weekly       every three weeks
monthly          every month
bi-monthly       every two months
tri-monthly      every three months
biannual         every six months
```

etc.

Comment: biweekly ( and monthly ) as well as tri- suffer from a confusion between meaning every two weeks, or twice a week. I would be very reluctant to use them.

Comment: Why on earth would you correctly apply bi- and tri- all the way through, then botch it on _biannual_?

Answer (score 0):

A smattering of people are using the term *semibiannual* online to designate one quarter of the year.

Answer (score -2):

You might make use of Latin prefix quadri- quadru- E.g

> Quadrennial

Comment: *Quadrennial* means "every four years", like *biennial* means "every two years". Since *biannual* means "twice a year" (well, according to most people...), you might get away with *quadriannual*...

Comment: @lonesomeday, both quadri- and quadru- means: four or four times. [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/quadri-)

Comment: @George Edison, you may also use "trimonthly"

Comment: @Mustafa, the issue isn't the "quadri-" it's the "ennial" vs "annual". The former uses the count for the number of years, the latter uses the count for the occurrences per year.

Comment: @zzzzBov, could you please post a reference "annual" and "ennial" are different words and they are also different in meaning?

Comment: @Mustafa, I can do one better I can simply link you to the definition of [quadrennial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quadrennial). "Quadannual" isn't really used, because we say "quarterly". I can find [results for  "quadannuallly"](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_quadannually_mean), however.