# Why there are two different meanings for "triweekly"?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

**Context:** I am looking for a term to indicate a time period of 3 weeks/21 days

For instance, a "fortnightly" event would occur every 2 weeks/14 days.

**My Usage**:

> The "Read for the Visually Challenged" is a *{fill in word for 3 weeks}* event as part of CSR initiatives organised by our comapny.

When I searched online, I stumbled upon ***[Triweekly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/triweekly)***, an adjective with two entirely different meanings

> 1. occurring or appearing three times a week
> 2. occurring or appearing every three weeks

[Merriam-Webster]

Ideally, I mean #2, but will this create a confusion? Why does it mean 2 different time periods? Is there another word to indicate a period of exactly 3 weeks?

P.S: I am not looking for "monthly" since this event is conducted every 3 weeks and it could be possible that it occurs in the first and fourth week of the same month.

Comment: Related: [An event that recurs four times a year?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/55648/8019)

Comment: If it didn't have both meanings then it wouldn't be consistent with *biweekly* and *bimonthly*.

Comment: http://www.xkcd.com/1602/ obligatory xkcd

Comment: I'd avoid any terms that divide a week, since there's no way to do it evenly - 7 is not a multiple of 2 or 3 (or anything else since it's prime).  True, 365 is also not a multiple of 2 or 3 either, but you can get a lot closer to a half- or third-year than a half- or third-week.

Comment: I thought about this question and it is ave very good question, +1)

Comment: Sesquifortnightly?

Comment: Similarly, the word "third" is ambiguous. Would I mean every third occurance or  three times per occurance (ie. one third, two thirds, three thirds)?

Comment: Also closely related: *[Are there any words I can use to disambiguate “biweekly”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50658)* and *[“Biweekly”, “bimonthly”, “biannual”, and “bicentennial”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18540)*.

Comment: The actual answers to the literal question in your title are (1) Words in English are **absolutely undefined**, it is an absolutely rule-free space. (2) It is **the norm** that there is total ambiguity and indeed confusion in English. To repeat, **this is the normal situation**.  You couldn't "give examples of" this as it would be, say, 50% of every single instance English utterance which has ever occurred.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Confusingly (according to dictionary definitions) the same is also true of *biweekly*; *bimonthly*; and *biyearly*. All of them can mean *once every two...* or *twice per...*

In the case of *biannual* the OED gives its adjectival meaning as once every two years, but when used as a noun as meaning the same as *biennial*, i.e. every other year. *Semi-annual* can be often used to express "twice per year".

**In view of the dichotomous meanings of *biweekly*, *triweekly* etc. all I can suggest is that where there is likely to be confusion that you avoid their use, in favour of *once every three weeks* etc. The OED recommends the use of the terms *semi-weekly*, *semi-monthly*, *semi-annually* to avoid any confusion when *twice per...* is intended.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any thoughts on why or how two different meanings for the same word came about in the first place?

Comment: @BiscuitBoy The OED doesn't say. I suppose it was just that people started using them both ways until each method developed its own purchase. But the OED does comment:
*bi-weekly adj. (b)  Occurring or appearing twice in a ——; as in (The ambiguous usage is confusing, and might be avoided by the use of semi-; e.g. semi-monthly, semi-weekly; cf. half-yearly adj.)*

Comment: -1 Uh, I thought biannual means twice a year. In fact I never thought it means once every two years.

Comment: This is just wrong about years. A biannual event occurs twice per annum; a biennial one occurs twice each two years. I have never heard or used 'biyearly', but it appears to be in usage ambiguously - so why bother when biannual and biennial are unambiguous I don't know! As is so often the case: add more Latin for less ambiguity!

Comment: @Mehrdad I would agree that there is confusion over this. The OED gives the adjective *biannual* as meaning twice per year, but the noun as having the same meaning as *biennial*. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Mehrdad The noun really only relates to plants as far as I'm aware. I'm not a botanist, but I'd say that there probably couldn't be any ambiguity in that context.

Comment: @OllieFord I'm pretty sure biennial means just once every two years.

Comment: @Matt Yes, that is what I state above.

Answer (score 9):

"*Every three weeks" is the most unambiguous option.*

The problem appears to be in the semantic nature of the prefixes which carry  the double meanings:

***[Tri](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Tri%20)***:

> - word-forming element ***meaning "three, having three, once every three,"*** from Latin tres (neuter tria) or Greek treis, trias "three".

***[Bi](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bi-&allowed_in_frame=0):***

> - word-forming element ***meaning "two, twice, double, doubly, once every two,"***  etc., from Latin bi- "twice, double," from Old Latin dvi- (cognate with Sanskrit dvi-, Greek di-, Old English twi- "twice, double"), from PIE root *dwo- "two." Nativized from 16c. Occasionally bin- before vowels; this form originated in French, not Latin, and might be partly based on or influenced by Latin bini "twofold".

(Etynomline)

[Usage note](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bi-):

> - ***All words except biennial referring to periods of time and prefixed by bi- are potentially ambiguous.***  Since bi- can be taken to mean either “twice each” or “every two,” a word like biweekly can be understood as “twice each week” or “every two weeks.” ***To avoid confusion, it is better to use the prefix semi- to mean “twice each” ( semiannual; semimonthly; semiweekly) or the phrase twice a or twice each (twice a month; twice a week; twice each year),***  and for the other sense to use the phrase every two (every two months; every two weeks; every two years).

- Actual usage suggests  that the term "triweekly"  is not commonly used, probably because of its ambiguous nature: see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=triweekly%2Cevery%20three%20weeks%2C%20three%20times%20a%20week%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctriweekly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevery%20three%20weeks%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthree%20times%20a%20week%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: And as two is to *semi_*, three is to *?*.

Comment: @WS2 - Obviously, [road train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_train).

Comment: I'm sure *triweekly* is uncommon simply because it's not needed very often. I, for one, can't recall the last time I thought about an event that happened three times a week, or once every three weeks, and I can't think of any now.

Comment: @talrnu - actually three times a week is a fairly common expression according to Ngram

Comment: Fair enough - perhaps you're right, then.

Comment: For an event held three times a week it's better to say "every Monday, Wednesday, and Friday", rather than leave people to guess which 3 days.

Answer (score 5):

The only clear way to say it is "every three weeks" (or something similar). If you use words like `triweekly`, you will just confuse everyone. Even if their interpretation of the word is correct, they will be unable to rely on your interpretation also being correct and matching theirs.

Comment: The correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Why there are two different meanings for “triweekly”?

It's almost as though the language evolved rather than being properly designed.

> Is there another word to indicate a period of exactly 3 weeks?

Yes, "three-weekly".

And for the other meaning (three times a week): "thrice-weekly".

Answer (score 0):

Fortnightly is often used in UK and Australia when people what to convey “every two weeks”.

There’s also the (not so commonly used) prefix “sesqui”, from Latin, that implies “1 and half times”.

That said, you can use sesquifortinightly, that means every 3 weeks; sesquicentennial, that means every 150 years; and so on.

As we live in a world where non-native people represent a big portion of all English communication we have, you should not expect people to be familiar with such a word.

1 https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/sesqui

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, The word is relatively recent in origin. It is first recorded in the OED as late as 1832:

> W. T. Barry 17 May in American State Papers (1834) XV. 348   *The line of stages connecting Philadelphia and Delaware with the Eastern shore of Maryland and Virginia, has been increased from a bi-weekly, to a tri-weekly line.*

And, as can be seen was intended to mean three times a week. There is no clear evidence of its meaning once every three weeks until 1901.

> Daily News 12 Jan. 5/3   *In consequence of military restrictions..the advertisement sheet which has been appearing every week will be issued tri-weekly.*

> Context: I am looking for a term to indicate a time period of 3 weeks/21 days

As both meaning have now been established, I would recommend your not using "triweekly" but using a phrase so as to convey exactly what you intend.

Comment: Google Books has at least one earlier use (also meaning three times a week): "There are, likewise, nine printing-offices in Washington, and two daily papers, with an equal number of **tri-weekly ones**, and a paper published once a week." in Abraham Rees' [Cyclopædia](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Cyclop%C3%A6dia_Or_Universal_Dictionary/xDhOAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=triweekly&pg=PP609&printsec=frontcover) published serially between 1802 and 1820. This is in the entry for "Washington," so the copyright date, which I can't navigate to, is probably about 1820.

Answer (score 0):

Never found any confusion. 'Thrice-weekly,' three times a week; tri-weekly, every three weeks. Isn't that the universal usage of native English speakers? Maybe 'thrice' is not found in the residual English of the former colonies.

Answer (score -3):

1x3, three a week

3x1 = 3 weeks or once every 3 weeks.

It's short, it defies language barriers, and it works.