# Is there a ly word describing 5 times a week?

Tags: adjectives

I need a ly word for five times a week. Is there even such a word?

Comment: I can do it in four words: "daily on weekdays only" and maybe with three by dropping "only."  But not with just one.

Comment: @cobaltduck "Only" is a _ly_ word. Just saying.

Comment: @cobaltduck "daily on weekdays" seems redundant. "On weekdays" is enough, I think

Comment: But this is something different than what is being asked for. If I suggest to someone that they water their plants 5 times a week, or that they take a medication 5 times a week, I am not necessarily suggesting that they do it only on weekdays. Perhaps a neologism is required--pentaweekly?

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296556/why-there-are-two-different-meanings-for-triweekly for a discussion of why biweekly and triweekly should be avoided.  Thus, by extension, a word for five times per week should be avoided.  And surlawda makes another good point.

Comment: See [Notes to Reviewers](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7913/142322)

Answer (score 6):

There is ***[weekdaily](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/weekdaily)***, but it is not common:

> - (rare) Of, pertaining to, or occurring on weekdays; especially, occurring on every [weekday](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/weekday)
>
>   - *The travel activity of residents of Center City and Cottage District neighborhoods results in significantly lower average weekdaily carbon emission than the regionwide averages.* (2002, Roger Gorham, "Comparative Neighborhood Travel Analysis).
>       (Wiktionary)

Comment: Was about to post the same thing... Seems like Wiktionary is the only dictionary that has it though.

Comment: Certainly it's an obvious neologism.  It's not clear that it can be legitimately considered "legitimate", though.  Ngram doesn't find it.

Comment: Also, despite the "-ly" at the end, in the example given "weekdaily" seems to be used as an adjective, not a adverb.  With that in mind, one could probably just say "weekday" instead and still be understood.

Comment: In my entire English-speaking life of more than a few decades, I have never once heard "weekdaily" used. I would be very surprised and probably amused if I encountered it. When trying to help out, it's not the best policy to grab at anything that can be found, especially on Wictionary. It may make the OP subject to unwanted scrutiny to use a neologism for their purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its better to use **weekdays** for this purpose. *Why would you need a -ly?*

## [Weekdays](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weekdays)

> on weekdays repeatedly :  on any weekday
>
> *"takes a bus weekdays"*

*Weekdays* is used in a different manner as shown above. Meanwhile [*weekday*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weekday) means:

> any day of the week except Saturday and Sunday

This is assuming your **"5 days a week"** is not including the weekends.