# Is there a word for occurring four times a week?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to use this word to say how often my basketball team meets to practice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  Four times a *week* is not a duplicate of four times a *year*.  This question is probably un-answerable, but not a dup.

Comment: @cobaltduck: People do sometimes use [quad-weekly](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22quad+weekly%22), but that's inherently ambiguous (four times a week, or once every four weeks?). Whatever - comments on that earlier question include [*both **quadri**- and **quadru-** mean: four or four times*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55648/is-there-a-prefix-that-indicates-that-an-event-recurs-four-times-a-year#comment105124_55664), which about all there is to say here.

Comment: I think you're stuck with "four times a week". *Bi-weekly* can't even decide if it's every two weeks or twice a week.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Dupes shouldn't rely on comments and the only answer that mentions *quad* is at -1. I'll take this opportunity to point out that saying *"If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question."* basically says to new users, if we've duped your question and those answers don't work for you, just ask this same question again. There should be a button: *No, this is not a dupe and those answers didn't help me.* and *Yes, THIS answer helped me.* with a script that copy-pastes *their* selected answer.

Comment: why'd you dupe my question fumble fingers? there are no similar answered questions.

Comment: There is no such word, at least not one that would be recognized by more than one person in 100.

Comment: The word is *fourtimesaweek*.

Comment: I think that if you have to ask for such a word then any such word, if it exists, is unlikely to be correctly understood by the intended audience.

Answer (score 5):

**No, there is no word for "occurring four times a week".**

Even the common phrase "every other day" only means four times a week in alternate weeks. Just use the phrase "meets four times a week".

There could have been such a word if weeks were eight or twelve days long. But "four times a week" with seven-day weeks is not evenly distributed. If there were a word which unambiguously meant "four times a week" rather than "every four weeks", then it's likely to be so rare that no-one would know what it meant, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are best saying “meets four times a week on Sundays, Mondays, Thursdays and Saturdays” to provide all needed information. Using a word such as quarterweekly as suggested doesn’t provide anything but the bare bones information.

Answer (score -1):

***quarterweekly*** could work along long the lines of *quarterly*.

No matter that it isn't in a dictionary.  Nobody will need one to know what you mean.

(Thank you, @FumbleFingers, for the link to [is-there-a-prefix-that-indicates-that-an-event-recurs-four-times-a-year](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55649/153448).)